# Unable to solve a codechef puzzle?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/H1) apparently beginner level problem. But not even able to come up with a brute force approach.

Here is the problem statement:

> Johnny has some difficulty memorizing the small prime numbers. So, his computer science teacher has asked him to play with the following puzzle game frequently.
>
> The puzzle is a 3x3 board consisting of numbers from 1 to 9. The objective of the puzzle is to swap the tiles until the following final state is reached:
>
> ```
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9
> ```
>
> At each step, Johnny may swap two adjacent tiles if their sum is a prime number. Two tiles are considered adjacent if they have a common edge.
>
> Help Johnny to find the shortest number of steps needed to reach the goal state.
>
> #### Input
>
> The first line contains *t*, the number of test cases (about 50). Then *t* test cases follow. Each test case consists of a 3x3 table describing a puzzle which Johnny would like to solve.
>
> The input data for successive test cases is separated by a blank line.
>
> #### Output
>
> For each test case print a single line containing the shortest number of steps needed to solve the corresponding puzzle. If there is no way to reach the final state, print the number -1.
>
> #### Example
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 2
> 7 3 2 
> 4 1 5 
> 6 8 9 
>
> 9 8 5 
> 2 4 1 
> 3 7 6
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 6
> -1
> ```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you be more specific? Don't expect the community to solve this online. We can however offer help if you have a very *specific* issue.

Comment: yeah, I don't expect people to solve it for me either. All I want is an approach to start with. I can't even think of a direct and brute force approach to start with. So I am seeking any hints or ideas even if it is in plain English and not a pseudo code.

Comment: You want to study graph algorithms like Dijkstra and BFS.

Comment: graph seems to be an advance concept. This problem was classified as a cakewalk problem. There must be a direct approach to it.

Comment: You'll have to search through the possible "moves". You can use recursion for this keeping track of the shortest solution among all solutions. A BFS algorithm would be the first choice, but this is a relatively small search tree, so DFS will do fine as well (and thus recursion).

Comment: I think the classification of the problem is wrong -- BFS is the right approach (and I clicked through a few solutions to see that this is what they're doing). I'd call it an intermediate-level problem, and not a beginner-level problem.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Thanks for letting me know. I was totally confused about how come this is so easy and I can't even think straight. Could you please let me know how to approach it using BFS?

Comment: To me it is a backtracking problem, run through all choices given that constraint. Think of "choose->recurse->unchoose"

Comment: @SomeDude That would be depth first search, not breadth first.  Which if you do naively will cause you to get into an endless loop, and also doesn't solve the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start on Python for finding the distance to ALL boards that are reachable from the start.

```
start = '123456789'
needed_moves = {start: 0}
work_queue = [start]
while (len(work_queue)):
    board = work_queue.pop(0)
    for next_board in next_move(board):
        if next_board not in needed_moves:
            needed_moves[next_board] = needed_moves[board] + 1
            work_queue.append(next_board)
```

This is a standard pattern for a breadth first search.  Just supply a `next_move` function and some glue for the tests cases and you're good.

For a depth first search, just switch the queue for a stack.  Which really means do `work_stack.pop()` to pop the last element rather than `work_queue.pop(0)` to get the first one.